# MVVM Light : How to remove dependency of System.Windows.MessageBoxResult from DialogMessage

Tags: mvvm

I'm working on a MVVM application, using MVVM Light and on the whole I'm finding it very nice to work with. I have a nagging issue however and hope someone can help.

I'm using sending instances of `DialogMessage` from VM to the View to display dialogs. The result is sent back to my VM via a callback, all good so far.

However the result of the dialog (OK, Yes, No, Cancel etc) is sent back as a member of the `enum System.Windows.MessageBoxResult`. This seems to go against the View/ViewModel separation to me, `MessageBoxResult` is clearly a type from the UI and so the VM shouldn't be dependent upon this or anything from the `System.Windows` namespace.

What I'm looking for is someway of using `DialogMessage` with an alternative callback eg `Action<UserResult>;` rather than `Action<System.Windows.MessageBoxResult>;`, where `UserResult` is a type defined by me to represent the users choice without dependency on `MessageBoxResult`.

Is this possible or am I being too strict in me desire to keep UI concepts out of the VM?

Comment: @Blachshma Thanks for your reply. I will probably use your suggestion of wrapping DialogMessage and converting the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the second part of your question, when I started working with MVVM Light I too felt that receiving a `MessageBoxResult` back in the VM seems a little to UI-oriented.
On the other hand, if only the *name* was different - such as UserResult as you suggested - would that be sufficient for you?
If only the nameing of the class is a problem, I think you can let it slip. The **result** `Ok, Yes, No, Cancel` do not give an indication of whether a MessageBox was shown with buttons or whether it was some other kind of UI implementation (lets say a form with a combo box).

If it still bothers you, you can always create a wrapper for the `DialogMessage` which will raise the Dialog, get the `MessageBoxResult` and return a `UserResult` which can be an enum with the same values (think of it as a simple converter).
But as I said, I think it might be an overkill...